# Marker not visible in Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have followed every step in `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api` and getting the map but when i try to implement marker then its not showing marker or not able to change setMapType or do anything with the map.

here's my code:

```
static final LatLng latlong = new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    latlong).title("Hello world"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

There is no error but guess i'm missing something... help pls... and sorry for such silly question.

Comment: That marker is in the ocean... are you sure you're looking for it in the right spot?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try to change your code, implementing `OnMapReadyCallback`([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))) with `getMapAsync`.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) is written nice example from documentation.

Comment: If there was no crash, getMap must have returned non-null, so this cannot be the problem in this case. (In general, though, it is good to move towards using getMapAsync always).